# Integral of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{(\frac{1}{2}+iw\cos \theta)^4} d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I tried to solve the following integral using Residue Theorem but I am not sure about its singular values. Any other way without using Residue Theorem is also appreciated.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{(\frac{1}{2}+iw\cos \theta)^4} d\theta
\end{equation}

Here $i$ is the imaginary unit and w is an arbitrary real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$R(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac12+iwx\right)^4}.$$Then the integral that you wish to compute is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$. Let\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac1zR\left(\frac{z+1/z}2,\frac{z-1/z}{2i}\right)\\&=-\frac{4z\left(z^2-1\right)^2}{\left(w z^2+w-i z\right)^4}.\end{align}Then the poles of $f$ are located at$$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4w^2}}{2w}i$$and the only pole inside the unit circle is the one with the $-$ sign. The residue of $f$ at that point is $\frac8{\left(4w^2+1\right)^{5/2}}$ and therefore your integral is equal to$$\frac{16\pi}{\left(4w^2+1\right)^{5/2}}.$$

Comment: The guidance is great. I am not clear about the residue of $f$ at $z_0=\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4w^2}}{2w}i$. Since this point is a forth order pole, in order to get the residue, I need to calculate $\frac{1}{3!} \frac{d^3}{dz^3}f(z)\cdot (z-z_0)^4$ and evaluate the formula at $z=z_0$. The formula I get is $\frac{1}{3!} \cdot \frac{12(z_1+z)(5z_1^2z^2-z_1^2-8z_1z-z^2+5)}{(z_1-z)^7}$, where $z_1$ is the other pole outside the unit circle. After I plug $z_0$ into this formula, I don't get $\frac{8}{(4w^2+1)^{5/2}}$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It looks fine. After simplification, and using your notation,$$f(z)(z-z_0)^4=-\frac{4z(z^2-1)^2}{w^4(z-z_1)^4}$$and I did get that$$f'''(z_0)=\frac{48}{(1+4w^2)^{5/2}}.$$

Comment: I checked my calculation carefully and it worked out. Thank you so much.